# Simple command or environment variable to print the current namespace in openshift/kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Is there some command for this? It irks me that Openshift takes pride in having "-o yaml" and "-o json" commands to avoid having to use cut/grep/awk, but for listing the current project this seems to be the only way to do it:

```
[root@bart-master ~]# oc project
Using project "default" on server "https://api.bart.mycluster.com:6443".
[root@bart-master ~]# oc project | cut -d '"' -f2
default
```

Comment: whats the point? You can always just run the command to set the current project so you are 100% guaranteed to be using the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current project(namespace) using each `oc` and `kubectl` CLIs as follows

```
$ oc config view --minify -o 'jsonpath={..namespace}'
$ kubectl config view --minify -o 'jsonpath={..namespace}'
```

Answer (score 3):

The `oc project` CLI command already has this built in. You can pass the `-q` or `--short` arguments to `oc project` in order to get the namespace name alone.

In general, `oc` has *great* help support that you can get by appending `-h` to the end of any command (including `oc project`) to get helpful arguments like this.